# How set date format yyyy/MM/dd into datagridview rows c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, date-format

**How can I get this date format? yyyy/MM/dd, I currently receive this format at exit 14.08.2017**

This is my code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = DateTime.Parse(ev.Attribute("Start").Value).ToShortDateString();
```

Please look at my code, in other similar cases, I could not find the same situation..

Thanks everyone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5yIM.png)

Comment: I tried that, the same format is coming out again..

Comment: Have you tried `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");` Is that what you want?

Comment: Try with DateTime.ParseExact(ev.Attribute("Start").Value,"yyyy/MM/dd",null);

Comment: Thanks for the answers, with ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); I tried not to work. This second comment shows me a mistake:"FormatException was unhandeld"

Comment: "When converting a string to Datetime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the datetime object."

Comment: This is a solution: DateTime.Parse(ev.Attribute("Start").Value).ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");